# Wordpress on Appengine - Plugins not installing

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to install plugins locally with add new > upload plugin. I get these errors ...

(1) With App Engine WP Plugin activated:

Fatal error: make_call(): Remote implementation for app_identity_service.GetAccessToken failed in C:\dev\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\php\sdk\google\appengine\runtime\RealApiProxy.php on line 48

(2) With App Engine WP Plugin deactivated:

Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2017/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

(Note I have linked a service account to the storage bucket and given write permission)

Answer (score 0):

Install them on your local machine to insure that they are saved in the GitHub repo that you push to appengine.. (it is not clear how you are doing it.

Comment: Yes I'm attempting to install them on local machine, the sated errors then result after pressing upload.